# Ant task vs Shell script

Tags: performance, shell, ant

I see a lot of places in my office where `ant tasks` are used to move files from one place to another and also do some tasks on these files.However all this can be done with `shell scripts`.

My question is ,

In what cases is `ant` preferred over `shell scripts` ?

What are the benefits of using `ant` over a `shell scripts` for doing same set of tasks.

One advantage `ant` has is that it works on all platforms,other than that are there any `performance` related advantages ?

Comment: `ant` only works on platforms where it has been installed, same as shell scripts.  Since `sh` is a standard tool, it is more likely to be installed, so I question that as an advantage of `ant`.  That many developers may write non-standard compliant shell scripts is certainly a problem, but it is incorrect to equate that with a lack of availability.

Comment: can you install `sh` on windows platform ? You can't.But `ant` can be.

Comment: When you are already using Ant (which often happens when your software use Ant as the build tool), use Ant tasks to perform the operations. When you are not using Ant and you want to choose a tool, choose shell script, or other script languages.

Comment: Well,that's the question,why use `ant` in first place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question as to why ANT should be preferred to shell scripts is two-fold:

1. ANT is a tool that has achieved widespread adoption and is likely to
   be already installed on a developer's workstation. Compared to one
   of it's main predecessors, make, ANT is a lot more standardized and
   cross-platform.
2. ANT is a tool familiar to developers. Used to build their code so they will often extend the ANT script to deploy their application as
   well. Indeed many vendors offer ANT tasks for this purpose.

There are no performance benefits, really. Java is slow for command-line usage.

But..... I would advise against playing the "performance" card. Let's pretend that your application does not support windows (Which is odd considering a Java application should support all plaforms...): I have seen shell script driven deployments decend into chaos attempting to reconcile the various ways different unix operating system commands work. Commands like "tar", "awk", etc can be subtly different which leads to additional platform support logic in your script.

In conclusion I would use neither. I choose a hybrid approach of using [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) for general scripting. It is a java based scripting language and embeds the full power of ANT. Being a java based scripting language means it will work on all platforms. In the interest of fairness it should also be noted that there are other language options. Ruby is certainly worthy of mention since it has spawned a set of configuration management technologies that are well worth evaluation. (See [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) and [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/))

Answer (score 0):

In practice, it boils down to Windows support. If you're in a Unix shop and don't want to introduce new stuff to devs, there are two alternatives i've used with success:

- Plain old shell script with Git Bash. Git Bash comes with the Git windows distribution (http://git-scm.com/). If you're doing automation, you can launch shell scripts like so: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -- ./BUILD
- Node script. Again it's one easy installer, it's javascript, and you can use something like ShellJS (https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs) to get very close to Unix shell script / Makefiles.