# Which are the reasons to use Ant/Phing/etc over shell script?

Tags: shell, ant, build, phing, build-tools

I'm developing several PHP projects, and I've started using Phing as build tool.

But I realised that everything I do with Phing, I could do just with shell commands. So I've started asking to my self if using Phing is worth.

If I assume the builds will **always** execute on a Linux system, does make sense to use build tools, instead of shell script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Phing/Ant over Bash and Make?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564085/why-phing-ant-over-bash-and-make)

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with Phing but I have worked with maven, ant, gradle and shell scripts. Main advantage of build tools are that they are operating system independent. For example, we execute same ant scripts on our local machine as well as production servers by loading different properties file. On windows we use bat file and on RHEL we use shell script to invoke same ant script.

Also, your assumption that build always execute on Linux system is not correct. In future some one can take a decision to switch to different OS. We just switched our servers from windows to linux. if some one wrote the whole build script in powershell, you can imagine it would be difficult to migrate.

**If we don't have windows I don't think we needed any of the build tools.**

Similar to your question:

[Why Phing/Ant over Bash and Make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564085/why-phing-ant-over-bash-and-make)